# Вывести друга по дате рождения

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть не большой скрипт:

```
$STH = $bd->query("SELECT a.*, b.*
     from users a INNER JOIN frnds b
     where MONTH(a.birthdateDay) = MONTH(NOW())
     AND   DAY(a.birthdateDay)   = DAY(NOW())
     AND a.id = b.user_two 
     ORDER BY a.birthdateDay");
while ($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "$row[username]";
}
```

Стараюсь вывести друга по дате рождения, но выводит всех людей. Структура друзей.

```
frnds_id, user_one, user_two.
```

Помогите пожалуйста вывести не всех пользователей по дате рождения, а только друзей пользователя.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev

1. У вас условие джойна идет где-то глубоко в отрыве от джойна
2. У вас нет никакой привязки к пользователю, чьих друзей вы ищете

В общем случае все решится просто дополнительным `AND b.use_one = <id>`

Comment: @Etki Спасибо большое заработало, только вот теперь например есть 2 пользователя и они дружат вот у одного показывает день рождения друга, а у другого нет.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev, потому что, получается, это его собственный день рождения?

Comment: @Etki Нет.Смотрите есть 2 юзера с id например 1,2 и они дружат с друг другом. У них день рождения в один день например так вот. у id1 показывает то что id2 день рождения,а вот когда заходит id2 то у него не показывает то что у id1 день рождения.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev сложно что-то сказать без дополнительных подробностей. Попробуйте эмулировать запросы из какого-нибудь phpmyadmin, подставляя предполагаемые ID.